# Alternation not matching as expected in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Learning sed, I want to change the drive letter of the following input lines from 'a' to 'd':

```
http:/a/foo/bar.txt
http:/a/bar/foo.txt
file:/a/foobar.txt
http:/b/foo/bar.txt
http:/c/foobar.txt
```

I'm using the following sed expression:

```
sed 's_^\(http|file\):/a_\1:/d_' in.txt
```

That is: if a line starts with either 'http' or 'file' then follows with ':/a', capture the protocol as group 1, and replace the 'a' with a 'd'. Or at least it's supposed to be.

However, I can't seem to get the alternation operator '|' to work. If I just use 'http' or 'file' on it's own for the group, the command behaves as expected, if I use 'http|file' for the group, then none of the lines match:

```
mbook:sed rob$ sed 's_^\(http\):/a_\1:/d_' in.txt
http:/d/foo/bar.txt
http:/d/bar/foo.txt
file:/a/foobar.txt
http:/b/foo/bar.txt
http:/c/foobar.txt
mbook:sed rob$ sed 's_^\(file\):/a_\1:/d_' in.txt
http:/a/foo/bar.txt
http:/a/bar/foo.txt
file:/d/foobar.txt
http:/b/foo/bar.txt
http:/c/foobar.txt
mbook:sed rob$ sed 's_^\(http|file\):/a_\1:/d_' in.txt
http:/a/foo/bar.txt
http:/a/bar/foo.txt
file:/a/foobar.txt
http:/b/foo/bar.txt
http:/c/foobar.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `|` or use extended regular expressions

```
sed -r 's_^(http|file):/a_\1:/d_'
```

Comment: Thanks sverre, switching to extended regex did the trick. However, in my version of sed, the switch was -E, not -r :)

Answer (score 4):

Try escaping the alternation too:

```
sed 's_^\(http\|file\):/a_\1:/d_' in.txt
```

Very related: [Use of alternation in sed regex](https://superuser.com/questions/111996/use-of-alternation-in-seds-regex).

Comment: Nope, this doesn't change the behaviour for this example, does it work for you Mat (maybe a sed version issue)? Switching to extended regex and removing all the escapes worked, as Sverre suggested.