# Regex that matches 2 exact phrases

Tags: sed, pipe

I have already checked dozens of questions but I cannot seem to find the right solution for my case.

I am using `sed` to find some strings of the output of a tool and delete them. The output I'm dealing with is the following:

```bash
...
sipdir.online.lync.com has address 52.112.67.51
sipdir.online.lync.com has IPv6 address 2603:1037:0:2::b
example.com has address 87.211.67.123
blablabla.com has IPv6 address 2503:2037:0:3::b
...
```

I want to delete the strings **has address** and **has IPv6 address**. So far I have tried many combinations like the one below without luck.

*example output piped to sed ->* `sed -e 's%(has address )|( has IPv6 address)%%g'`

Comment: Then do not use parentheses, remove them. `sed -E 's%has address | has IPv6 address%%g'` as in POSIX BRE, `(` and `)` are literal chars, not metacharacters.

Comment: already tried that @WiktorStribiżew but it does not work

Comment: try to isolate `has address` with a an optional capture of `IPv6` within

Comment: You need `-E`, niot `-e`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternation not matching as expected in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236905/alternation-not-matching-as-expected-in-sed)

Comment: What a mess! `-E` solved my question, I forgot there was a difference. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew write that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. Edit: I mean this: `sed -E 's%has address | has IPv6 address%%g'`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this approach:

```
% sed -E 's/has address //;s/has IPv6 address //' /tmp/xxx
sipdir.online.lync.com 52.112.67.51
sipdir.online.lync.com 2603:1037:0:2::b
```

From [Sed documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-script-overview)

> Commands within a script or script-file can be separated by semicolons (;) or newlines (ASCII 10). Multiple scripts can be specified with -e or -f options.

```
sed '/^foo/d ; s/hello/world/' input.txt > output.txt
sed -e '/^foo/d' -e 's/hello/world/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/has( IPv6)? address //g' file
```

Replact `has address`  or `has IPv6 address`  with nothing.

The same solution without the `-E` option:

```
sed 's/has\( IPv6\)\? address //g' file
```

N.B. The `g` flag is probably superfluous since the examples only occur once per line.